# Reference error on using Google Analytics tracker in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, google-analytics

I am using google analytics tracker in my windows phone app. Below is the nuget link

https://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleAnalyticsTracker.WindowsPhone/

If I build solution I am getting this error

> type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' exists in both
>   'f:\Working\Tel -
>   new\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.2.1.2\lib\sl4-wp71\System.Threading.Tasks.WP71.dll'
>   and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0\mscorlib.dll'

How should I resolve this error?

Comment: Try to remove reference to "System.Threading.Tasks.WP71".. your project is WP8 isn't it?

Comment: Yes, WP8. If I remove that dll than code breaks on analytics execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install newer [`GoogleAnalyticsTracker.WP8`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleAnalyticsTracker.WP8/) package for Windows Phone 8 project, instead of legacy `GoogleAnalyticsTracker.WindowsPhone`. As suggested in the Nuget page you linked in question :

> LEGACY PACKAGE - Use GoogleAnalyticsTracker.WP7 or GoogleAnalyticsTRacker.WP8 instead - .... [[GoogleAnalyticsTracker.WindowsPhone](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleAnalyticsTracker.WindowsPhone/)]